# When No Route Matches, getting list of all available routes; how to disable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm not a rails developer but have been asked to look into this issue. When running the rails app locally or even in production, if we use a url that doesn't match a route like:

```
http://somedomain.com/fjdklajflsajflsd
```

The rails app displays a Routing Error and then displays a very nice looking table of every available route in the application. I'm wanting to know a way to turn that off so it just displays a 404.

Comment: Are you sure you are in production? It should default to public/404.html in production. In development it shows the errors

Comment: I'm sure it is happening in what the organization calls "production". That doesn't mean it was deployed "as production". I'll have to research that.

Answer (score 0):

Just create file in `/public` directory named `404.html.erb` and it will be used to display 404 errors.

If you put there file called `500.html.haml` it will be used for any 500 error on your site. I am not sure will it work on development, but on production it will (atleast I use it that way)

Comment: Those files already exist. I can access them directly, but they are not being used otherwise.

Comment: Have you changed the content of the file?

Comment: No, I haven't touched them.

Comment: Change the content of the file `404.html.erb` to just some plain html that you want to display, and it will be used. By default the content has table of routes that are displayed to you. Change the content of the file, it will be used for display.

Comment: Ok, what I meant was "I" didn't change it. But it was changed to just show a 404 message. When I go to /404.html, that is what I want. It just isn't doing it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. In production.rb this setting was not correct.

```
# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```